# Using if and count if on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Using if and count if on multiple criteria]

How to solve the excel issue which I am facing.
Please refer to the above image.

Comment: So what have you tried?  Seems like simple COUNTIFS() will work.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott said a simple Countifs() will do:

```
B       C

Alax    Yes
John    No
Ali     Yes
Asgar   Yes
Rahul   No
Alax    No
John    Yes
Tim     No
Rahul   Yes
```

B2:B10 and C2:C10 the 2 columns Name and Yes/No Data, use: 
Total Yes:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,$B12,$C$2:$C$10,"Yes")
```

Total No:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,$B12,$C$2:$C$10,"No")
```

B12 is the first under Name Alax and drag both formulas down each in the same column
Keep the $ and change references to correspond your Data.